# one-to-one association in Ektorp

Tags: couchdb, ektorp

Is it possible to define a one-to-one association in Ektorp? In the Ektorp documentation I only found how to embed a list of objects into an object referenced by foreign key.
I want to produce a document like:

```
{
  name: "John",
  surname: "Smith",
  address: {
    street: "Abc Street",
    zip: "12345",
    city: "My City"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding a complete document like this is very friendly. One straightforward way to do this is by defining a `Contact` class that has an `Address` class.

```java
// Contact.java
package com.example;

public class Contact extends org.ektorp.support.CouchDbDocument {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Address address;

    //... constructors and/or setters

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getSurname() { return surname; }
    public Address getAddress() { return address; }
}

// Address.java
package com.example;

public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String zip;
    private String city;

    //... constructors and/or setters

    public String getStreet() { return street; }
    public String getZip() { return zip; }
    public String getCity() { return city; }
}
```

When written to the database, it will produce a document that looks like:

```
{
   "_id": "590ede48b04e7c61914c677f0f000b57",
   "_rev": "1-fae3423a6ea58741dca18764a39e48a9",
   "name": "John",
   "surname": "Smith",
   "address": {
       "street": "Abc Street",
       "zip": "12345",
       "city": "My City"
   }
}
```

Comment: that is the way to do it